# How do I find out if my husband got married to someone in the UK before he divorced me in the US?

Tags: united-kingdom, marriage, public-records

How do I find out if my husband got married to someone else in the UK before we got divorced in the US? I have both their names and the possible date of the marriage.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you can [order a copy of the marriage certificate](https://www.gov.uk/order-copy-birth-death-marriage-certificate) from the General Register Office.

(The following info is for a marriage which took place in England or Wales.  For Scotland or Northern Ireland, the process could be different; see links on the above site.)

The application process will ask for the "GRO index reference", which you probably don't have, but it is optional.  You can instead specify the names of the spouses and the date and place of the marriage, and there is a small extra fee for the search.  There's more info [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/general-register-office-gro-certificate-application-forms/general-register-office-gro-application-from-guidance-notes-accessible-version).

If you don't know the place of the marriage, you may need to do more research first; that's probably beyond the scope of Law.SE.  You may also be able to contact the GRO and ask if there is a way to have them search without it.